# What does happen to accepted posters if no author attend to present?

Tags: publications, conference, presentation, online-publication, poster

One of our posters has been accepted with "Strong merit" at ACM DEV 2016. We have finalized the draft and sent the camera ready version to the authority. But this year's venue is Nairobi and a 5 days trip to there will cost about a lot of money. And as a student if I cannot afford to attend the conference, what will they do with my poster? Will they include in their library? If not will it be considered unpublished?

PS: All the co-authors of the paper are undergraduate students and none can afford to attend.

Comment: Different conferences have different policies.  Maybe someone here knows about the policy of this specific conference, but you'll get a more certain answer by reading the written policies of the conference or contacting the organizers.

Comment: You might get an answer "Please direct any questions to acmdev16posters@gmail.com."

Comment: Why submit a paper or poster to a conference you don't plan to attend, even if the paper or poster is accepted?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, Hard to know if you will have travel funds sometimes.

Comment: @scrappedcola We thought that there might be some general answer.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan We had an overview of plane fare from the internet which I could afford. But those economic plans are not available during conference days that exceeded the amount I am willing to spend.

Answer (score 2):

As someone commented, different conferences have different policies. For those I'm accustomed to, conference papers are usually not published in the proceedings if none of the authors show up at the conference.

If I understand correctly your situation, I would proceed as follows:

- First, contact the conference secretary and explain your critical situation of undergraduate students with no university funding, asking whether they would be able to provide student support (e.g., fee waiving, cheap lodging in student's dormitory etc.) for one of the authors.
- If the previous point is unsuccessful, try at least to find someone from your university who is going to attend and that could bring your poster to the conference, attaching it during the poster session on your behalf. Explain this solution to the organizers and hope for the best.

Comment: Actually I tried the first point. About the second option, one of my professors has two papers and five posters accepted in that conference. But as the rule of the conference says none can present more than two, he won't be even able to present all of the posters done under his supervision. Hence can we just send a hard copy of our poster with him. Will that suffice?

Comment: @Dipto_Das It's really up to the organizers; the only way to know is to inquire with them. The answer can also depend on the number of attendees that are expected. If I were in the organizers, I'd be willing to give an opportunity to publish to a group of undergraduate student without funding, but others might have different ideas.

Comment: @Dipto_Das - Contact the organizers and ask them to make an exception to the maximum of 2 rule.

Answer (score 0):

Different conferences will have different policies. You should discuss this with the conference itself. I have been to venues where this is largely met with a shrug and a blank board, and some where not showing up to present can be penalized with a multi-year ban on submitting.